# How do further optimize the code to get over TLE error?

Tags: optimization, python-3.6

I am solving some problems from CodeChef but I am stuck on a problem https://www.codechef.com/MAY19B/problems/MATCHS.I got that problem is Dynamic Programmming problem.So I have used functools.lru_cache to save function results.But I am getting TLE error in some test cases.How can I further optimize the code?
Following is the problem:

Ari and Rich are playing a pretty confusing game. Here are the rules of the game:

```
1. The game is played with two piles of matches. Initially, the first pile 
  contains N matches and the second one contains M matches.
2. The players alternate turns; Ari plays first.
3. On each turn, the current player must choose one pile and remove a 
  positive number of matches (not exceeding the current number of matches 
  on that pile) from it.
4. It is only allowed to remove X matches from a pile if the number of 
  matches in the other pile divides X.
5. The player that takes the last match from any pile wins.
```

Solve(N,M)
 1. If its Ari's turn and N%M==0 then Ari wins else Rich wins.
 2. If N%M!=0 then player try every possible moves and check if he wins any one of them
    in end.

```py
from functools import lru_cache 

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def Solve(X,Y,Player=True):
    if X%Y==0:
        return Player
    else:
        temp=X
        X=X%Y
        if Player==Solve(max(X,Y),min(X,Y),not Player):
            return Player
        while temp!=X+Y:
            X=X+Y
            if Player==Solve(max(X,Y),min(X,Y),not Player):
                return Player
        return not Player
```

Comment: This seems to belong to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. You might want to try your chances there.

Answer (score 1):

The game is played with two piles of matches. Initially, the first pile 
  contains N matches and the second one contains M matches.
2. The players alternate turns; Ari plays first.
3. On each turn, the current player must choose one pile and remove a 
  positive number of matches (not exceeding the current number of matches 
  on that pile) from it.
4. It is only allowed to remove X matches from a pile if the number of 
  matches in the other pile divides X.
5. The player that takes the last match from any pile

Answer (score 0):

How about storing The calculations for values of x and y , suppose your solve function comes across some element (14,5) , then it will calculate who wins using the while loop and return you some value . Now suppose your function comes across (19,5) then it will calculate value for (4,5) ,(9,5) ,(14,5). And here as you see (14,5) gets calculated twice. Now imagine the scenario when the numbers are 10^6 and 10^9 big  , in this case your program will waste a lot of time calculating the value of those case whose value is already calculated.  So Finally

**> Try To Store the pre - calculated values into an list**

Comment: the LRU-cache used for the same purpose

Comment: Looking at the inputs there's no way you can solve the question by this approach there must be a mathematical approach @ADITYAJOSHI try doing that dp isn't going to help with this